# How to do a Django query from a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

So i have a table with vehicles in my DB, each vehicle has a relationship with an user in the Users table and each user has a company value. I need to get all the vehicles that have a user that has an specific compay value.

```
example: query = vehicles.users(company = company)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relationship between vehicles and users is ManyToMany, and the relationship between company and user is OneToOne, you could do:

```py
query = vehicles.objects.filter(user__company__id="my_company_id")
```

Comment: thnks it worked!!!